# How can I extract all .tar.gz files while maintaining the directory structure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, tar

I am working on a program to unzip/extract all `.tar.gz` files in a given folder. This folder can have several sub directories with multiple `.tar.gz` files as well. I am trying to extract all of them, while maintaining the folder structure, but running into some issues.

My current code is below, `extractall()` seems to only extract to the current working directory, and I can't quite figure out how to maintain the directory structure.

```
for zipped_file in pathlib.Path(path).glob('**/*.tar.gz'):
    tar = tarfile.open(zipped_file, 'r:gz')
    tar.extractall()
    tar.close()
```

Comment: Change the CWD to where you want to extract to before extracting.

Comment: `os.walk()` might be better approach

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html

```
TarFile.extractall(path=".", members=None, *, numeric_owner=False)
    Extract all members from the archive to the current working directory or directory path.
```

So:

```
import os

for path, directories, files in os.walk('/foo/bar'):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith(".tar.gz"):
            tar = tarfile.open(os.path.join(path,f), 'r:gz')
            tar.extractall(path=path)
            tar.close()
```